# Gigya Api_Invalid request signature

Tags: c#, gigya

I am trying to acess to a gigya api using sdk.
I am using a secret key but I have a signature problem.
Here is my C# code:

```cs
string apiKey = "xxxx";
string secretKey = "xxxxx";
string method = "accounts.login";
GSRequest request = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey, method, true);
request.APIDomain="eu1.gigya.com";
request.SetParam("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.SetParam("loginID","xxx@xxx.com");
request.SetParam("password","******");  
GSResponse response = request.Send();
if (response.GetErrorCode() == 0){
    Report.Info("WE ARE OKEEY HERE");
}
else{
    Report.Error("Uh-oh, we got the following error:{0}", response.GetLog());
}
```

The error I got is:

```
"errorCode": 403003,
"errorDetails": "Invalid request signature"
```

How resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it the Partner secret you are passing or an app/userKey secret? if the latter, you also need to pass the userKey parameter.

Comment: i can't seem to code-format a comment here.. https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.login+REST#accounts.loginREST-SampleRequests
"GSRequest request = new GSRequest(apiKey, secretKey, method, null, true, userKey);"

Comment: @Levi added the userKey and it works.thank you for your help